# Select statement return if there is a value and if there is no value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssms-2017

Here's my code of the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SELECT NOTES as DeletionNote 
FROM STCRCHF_LOG 
WHERE STHTR_ =  @transferNo

IF ( @@ROWCOUNT = 0)
```

If there is data found, I just want to return the string of NOTES. Else if it doesn't have data, I just want to return an empty string or null.

Screenshot (executed stored procedure):

If there is data found. At my program on the web server side it gets the data.

[image: If there is a data]

If there is no data. In my program on the web server side it causes a `NullReferenceException`

[image: if there is no data]

Comment: Will you be expecting multiple rows for a `@transferNo` ?

Comment: Side note - TransforNo seems to be a number. Why is it a unicode string?

Comment: But don't you handle NullReferenceException in web program level. Handling such exception at programming level is always a wise idea.

Comment: @Squirrel i do have only one data for each transfer data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only a single record is possible then:

```
select coalesce((SELECT NOTES FROM STCRCHF_LOG 
WHERE STHTR_ =  @transferNo), '') as DeletionNote
```

If multiple records are possible then the following will ensure at least one row is returned:

```
SELECT NOTES as DeletionNote FROM STCRCHF_LOG WHERE STHTR_ =  @transferNo
union all select '' /* or null if preferred */ where not exists (SELECT 1 FROM STCRCHF_LOG WHERE STHTR_ =  @transferNo)
```

Comment: Good answer, though the alias should be on the outer select.

Comment: Also, please note that it will only work for a select statement that returns a single value. If the select statement returns more than one row, this will fail with "Subquery returned more than 1 value...".

Comment: @ZoharPeled I do have only one data in each transfer no.  Thanks Guys!! I'l check !

Comment: The solution you posted for multiple rows is similar to the one I had in mind, with one exception: In case the query gets more complicated, for the second solution I would suggest using a cte or even a table variable to hold the results (in case it's a long running query) instead of repeating the entire query in the `exists`. Still, I would upvote again if I could :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed - I would certainly do that if there was additional complexity. Thanks for your kind words.

Answer (score 1):

Another way which I like is to use a dummy value and OUTER APPLY like so.

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (someId INT IDENTITY, Col1 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @table(Col1) VALUES ('record 1'),('record 2');

DECLARE @id INT = 11;

SELECT f.Col1
FROM   (VALUES(NULL)) AS dummy(x)
OUTER APPLY 
(
  SELECT t.Col1
  FROM   @table AS t
  WHERE t.someId = @id
) AS f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `If(DataTable.Rows.Count >0)` check at your web programming level to avoid `NullReferenceException`. Based on the condition you can make the decision what to do with the further logic at web program.

It is always wise idea to handle such exception from programming level. Think of scenario where somebody else make changes in SQL query without knowing the effect of web usages of the code.

Comment: What makes you think this is a website? or that it's even used outside sql server?

Comment: @zohar question has web server side. Mostly NullReferenceException always raised where we call sql code outside of the sql server. Also I did not use any where website. 

Be it any programming language the check point I suggest is part of the best practices of the programming. I am not perfect and I am trying to pretend at least.

Comment: Corret, I've missed that... need more coffee, I guess.

Comment: No worries @Zohar.. Coffee always helps us always go and get it. I wish I could join on Coffee table :)